# error laravel 5.2 ReflectionException in Route.php line 286:

Tags: laravel

https://github.com/szystems/jireh.git

les dejor este repositorio por si quieren ver los archivos completos espero puedan ayudarme ;)

hola espero puedan ayudar tengo un proyecto en el cual en mi servidor local funciona todo correcto pero al subirlo a un servidor compartido parece funcionar todo bien incluso puedo loguearme y ver consultas en listados de la base de datos pero al realizar una accion como crear editar o eliminar me sale este error

ReflectionException in Route.php line 286: Class jireh\http\Requests\VistavehiculoFormRequest does not exist viendo en otras respuestas por lo general es una coma o algun error en sintaxis pero revisandolo todo creo no tener ningun error mi archivo VistavehiculoFormRequest.php:

```html
<?php

namespace jireh\Http\Requests;

use jireh\Http\Requests\Request;

class VistavehiculoFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'contacto' => 'required|max:50',
            'tel_contacto' => 'required|max:20',
            'email_contacto' => 'email|max:255',
            'nombre' => 'required|max:100',
            'marca' => 'required|max:45',
            'modelo' => 'required|max:45',
            'linea' => 'required|max:45',
            'tipo' => 'required|max:45',
            'origen' => 'required|max:45',
            'precio' => 'required',
            'puertas' => 'required|max:5',
            'motor' => 'required|max:45',
            'cilindros' => 'required|max:5',
            'combustible' => 'required|max:45',
            'millas' => 'required|max:45',
            'descripcion' => 'max:500',
            'ac' => 'required|max:5',
            'full_equipo' => 'required|max:5',
            'estado' => 'required|max:45'     
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: El error parece no estar dado en esta clase sino mas bien en donde la empleas revisa a ver si te falta algun use en tu controladora o no este bien el nombre de espacio

Comment: creo que no me falta ningun use en mi controlador y como digo en servidor local todo funciona correctamente y en el servidor compartido no, estos son los que utilizo: <?php

namespace jireh\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use jireh\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use jireh\http\Requests\VistavehiculoFormRequest;
use jireh\Vistavehiculo;



use Carbon\Carbon; 
use DB;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Auth;
use jireh\User;

use jireh\Http\Requests\MensajeFormRequest;
use Mail;

Comment: Puede ser algún error con el archivo routes.php porque el request está bien.
También puede ser algo en el controlador.

Comment: pues como lo pondrias tu en routs.php?? lo he puesto asi Route::post('/show', 'VistavehiculoController@store'); y asi route::resource('vistavehiculos','VistavehiculoController'); de las dos maneras en local funciona y en servidor compartido no, especificamente uso uno de ipage.com este es el enlace: http://szystems.com/grupojireh/public/ especificamente en el apartado de vender vehiculo o inmueble pueden probar el formulario que es donde da error

Comment: Igual a ti gracias pero la respuesta del Reny Ramos fue la que arreglo el problema solo era la mayuscula en Html, gracias ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De casualidad llegaste a borrar o renombrar esa clase en algún momento? puede ser que este guardado en cache con el nombre anterior y no lo reconoce, intenta con:

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dumpautoload
```

Si no lo arregla intenta revisar donde estas utilizando ese form request, debe ser un error en esa parte.

-------EDIT--------

Por cierto, acabo de ver tu git y me fije en algo

```
use jireh\http\Requests\VistavehiculoFormRequest;
use jireh\Http\Requests\MensajeFormRequest;
```

No se si te fijas, pero el **http** esta en minúsculas, no se que tanto afecta eso (utilizo usualmente una herramienta que hace automáticamente esta parte) pero debería influir, he utilizado tinker para trabajar con clases y es case sensitive, intenta cambiar esa h por mayúscula y prueba pasando composer dump-autoload.

Comment: pues probare lo raro es que en servidor local en mi pc todo funciona normalmente y al subirlo al servidor todo funciona menos donde tengo tiene que usar cualquier request de cualquier controlador pero solo en servidor

Comment: este es el codigo de la funcion en el controlador al que lleva el formulario: public function store(VistavehiculoFormRequest $request)
    {
     $vehiculo=new Vistavehiculo;
     $vehiculo->contacto=$request->get('contacto');
 ..............  y sigue las instrucciones pero me imagino que es en public function store(VistavehiculoFormRequest $request)

Comment: Usualmente en esos casos se debe a cosas
-Error en el nombre, ya sea donde lo declaraste (use .... VistavehiculoFormRequest )

Comment: ok probare lo de http por Http y les aviso aunque composer mismo fue es que creo esto pero vere si ayuda en algo ;) ahora con lo del nombre use VistavehiculoFormRequest a que te refieres?? pues no se como podria haber un error, gracias por responder este es el enlace por si quieren ver la aplicacion funcionando en el servidor: http://szystems.com/grupojireh/public/

Comment: Gracias hermano eres un genio si tenias toda la razon la solucion fue poner Html con la mayuscula lo aprecio mucho era algo tan sencillo no se porque en servidor local si servia y en el servidor compartido no, muchas gracias

Comment: Creo, énfasis en Creo, recordar alguien que presentaba un problema parecido porque en su MAC de la oficina no había problema con ese aspecto (en ese sistema era case Insensitive) pero al continuar en el Ubuntu de su casa le daba error porque no reconocía la clase, no se si es tu caso, pero es algo que seria bueno que investigaras porque te lo permite en local.